# Which units/building reveal cloaked enemies in Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List of StarCraft II “Detectors?”](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15402/list-of-starcraft-ii-detectors)

When I switch between races, I seem to forget what I need to build to protect myself from cloaked enemies.  (Yeah, I'm a pretty inexperienced player.)  What reveals in each race?

Comment: Though the target here is a newer question, the data in [its answer is more comprehensive](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15402/list-of-starcraft-ii-detectors/15405#15405) by covering campaign-specific units and special abilities. Thus, we're closing it in that direction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Protoss:

- Observer
- Photon Cannon

Terran:

- Raven
- Missile Turret

Zerg:

- Overseer
- Spore Crawler

Comment: Thank you! That should elevate me from a really crappy player to a mediocre player! :)

Comment: Of especial note for Zerg is that an Overseer is an upgraded version of an Overlord. Unlike StarCraft 1, the Zerg do not necessarily gain observers galore. Don't forget!

Comment: The Terran also have two additional methods: the Orbital Command's Scanner Sweep to detect cloaked units, and the Ghost's EMP which temporarily disabled cloaking of cloaked units (even permanently clocked ones, such as Dark Templars).