# List of StarCraft II "Detectors?"

Tags: starcraft-2

As I understand, correct me if I'm wrong, each race has "detector" units which can see all cloaked units.

Is there a list of these buildings or units for each race?

Comment: Duplicate with [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/826/which-units-building-reveal-cloaked-enemies-in-starcraft-2)? I don't think there's any differences from detectors versus just being able to reveal cloaked units? Admittedly, the answer here is much more in-depth, so that gives more weight towards a close in this direction, though.

Comment: @Grace it's a duplicate, and this question (and its answer) are of higher quality.

Comment: @Oak That's why I figure I should close in this direction.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Protoss

**Units and Structures:**
[Observer](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Observer)
[Photon cannon](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Photon_Cannon)
[Revelation](https://liquipedia.net/starcraft2/Revelation) (Oracle ability)
*Single Player only:* [Purifier](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Campaign/Safe_Haven) (Safe Haven on Level Brutal)

### Terran

**Units and Structures**:
[Raven](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Raven)
[Missile turret](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Missile_Turret)
*Single Player only:* [Science vessel](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Campaign/Science_Vessel)

**Abilities:**
[Scanner Sweep](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Scanner_Sweep) (orbital command ability)
[EMP Shot](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/EMP_Round) (ghost ability) will reveal cloaked units for a short time

### Zerg

**Units and Structures**:
[Overseer](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Overseer)
[Spore crawler](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Spore_crawler)
*Single Player only:* [Spore cannon](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Campaign/Gates_of_Hell)
*Single Player only:* [Kerrigan](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Campaign/All-In#Kerrigan)

**Abilities:**
[Fungal Growth](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Fungal_Growth) (infestor ability)

Comment: could you add Protoss Oracle's revelation as well?